# Trying to create an ID for a vector in R

Tags: r

I  have this vector in R

```
A 
B
C
A
B
C
D
E
A
B
C
A
B
D
F
G
```

And I want to get to the following result:

```
A 1
B 1
C 1
A 2
B 2
C 2
D 2
E 2
A 2
B 2
C 2
A 3
B 3
D 3
F 3
G 3
```

So, in other words, I am trying to for ID to start a new number with the new case of "A". Obviously, it is just a part of the data, and my vector is much longer. Can anyone help with this?
Thanks

Comment: I think you missed one `A` there, All you need is just `cumsum(x == "A")`

Comment: @bgoldst You are mistaken. They clearly have the linebreaks in the [source of the original text](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65b47400-3f03-4c61-84cb-c8c27f0e6268/view-source) and simply didn't know how to use code formating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple application of `cumsum`:

```
data.frame(x, cumsum(x=='A'))
```

Comment: This solution is perfect. Thanks everybody